# How can i change the position of floatable form in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the ExtJS form which is `floating`

Now i want to give `%` margin `from top and left` but its not working.

Example is here :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dj

```
var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true,
     closable : true,
    y: '10%',
    x: '10%',

});
f.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below for size:

```
var leftPercent=10;
var rightPercent=10;
// Create a viewport, this automatically scales to the window height/width so is predictable in its size
var viewport=Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    items:[
        f
    ],
    listeners:{
        resize:function(){
            // if the form has been added to the viewport, change its position
            f && f.setPosition(viewport.getWidth()*(rightPercent/100), viewport.getHeight()*(rightPercent/100));
        }  
    }
});


var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    autoShow:true,
    floating: true,
    // set the initial position of the form (not necessarily needed)
    x:viewport.getWidth()*(rightPercent/100),
    y:viewport.getHeight()*(rightPercent/100)    
});
```

It should provide you a decent basis to improve/edit. The important things are:

1. The window is placed within a component/element which is known (e.g. the viewport per above)
2. The height/width of the parent container behave as predicted during user interaction with the view
3. Any alterations to the height width of the parent container, then lead the child container to reposition itself accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can change the position of Ext.form.Panel by using `setPosition()` function.

Eg:-

```
var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true,
     closable : true,
    y: '10%',
    x: '10%',

});
f.show();
f.setPosition(100, 200, true);
```

Comment: i want to use 10% from top position not hardcoded. can we do that with setposition

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

### Config:

region -> Defines the region inside

padding -> Specifies the padding for this component

```
var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true,
    closable : true,
    //padding : '10 0 0 20', // example: '10 0 0 20' (top, right, bottom, left).
    region : 'center'  // possible values north, south, east, west, and center

});
f.show();
```

Note: padding used for smaller variation.

Second try :

```
var f = new Ext.form.Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Foo',
    floating: true,
    closable : true,
    left : 10,
    top : 10

});
f.show();
```

Comment: But how can i display that form from 10% from top and 10% from left. And also center is not working. it displays the top left corner at the center of screen i want the centroid of form at the center. `y` alone works but `x` dont work

Comment: Please update with you full code, so that i will work on it and provide you solution.

Comment: In the above js fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1dj , the form is showing at the top left. if you remoce `x: 10%` then it shows 10% for y axis but if i add `x:10%` again then it goes to top left rather than 10% both on x or y axis. can you make the fiddle work

Comment: region : 'center'  is working fine in that fiddle. please copy my code and paste it in fiddle and have a look at it. it is working

Comment: i dont want center , i want 10% from top and left

Comment: Okay, let me try it and come back to you.

Comment: @user191542, its done. please check my second try code in the post.